# How to handle errors with JZMQ?

Tags: java, zeromq, jzmq

The [documentation for `Socket#recv()`](http://zeromq.github.io/jzmq/javadocs/org/zeromq/ZMQ.Socket.html#recv()) reads:

> Returns: [...] null on error.

How can I tell what the error was? I want to handle `EAGAIN` specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have very limited knowledge here but from the looks of it, the answer could be: 

"If [`Socket#recv()`](https://github.com/zeromq/jzmq/blob/master/src/main/java/org/zeromq/ZMQ.java#L1714) returns null and no [`ZMQException`](https://github.com/zeromq/jzmq/blob/master/src/main/java/org/zeromq/ZMQException.java) was thrown, an EAGAIN error occurred."

I followed the method calls and arrived at `do_read` in `Socket.cpp`
where it gets interesting on [line 83](https://github.com/zeromq/jzmq/blob/master/src/main/c%2B%2B/Socket.cpp#L83):

```
rc = zmq_recv (socket, message, flags);
int err = zmq_errno();
if (rc < 0 && err == EAGAIN) {
    rc = zmq_msg_close (message);
    err = zmq_errno();
    if (rc != 0) {
        raise_exception (env, err);
        return NULL;
    }
    return NULL;
}
if (rc < 0) {
    raise_exception (env, err);
    rc = zmq_msg_close (message);
    err = zmq_errno();
    if (rc != 0) {
        raise_exception (env, err);
        return NULL;
    }
    return NULL;
}
return message;
```

What I read here is that if something goes wrong, you get an `ZMQException` in Java
unless the error was `EAGAIN` and `zmq_msg_close` does not go wrong
(I am not sure what `zmq_msg_close` does, but I assume it rarely goes wrong).

But I don't have the environment to test this and I also don't really understand
how `raise_exception` works (source in [util.cpp](https://github.com/zeromq/jzmq/blob/master/src/main/c%2B%2B/util.cpp)):
what happens if two exceptions are raised/thrown in the same code-path (e.g. when `err` is not EAGAIN and `rc < 0`) and you can only catch one runtime-exception in Java?

On a side note, support for the EAGAIN error code was added in 
[this commit](https://github.com/zeromq/jzmq/commit/35c0a028acd4a36e2eff5a64c7e66ff198cb7743)
on May 15, 2015.

Comment: Yes! This appears to be it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

source code are:

```
    /**
         * Receive a message.
         *
         * @return the message received, as an array of bytes; null on error.
         */ 
        public final byte[] recv()
        {
            return recv(0);
        }

        /**
         * Receive a message.
         *
         * @param flags
         *            the flags to apply to the receive operation.
         * @return the message received, as an array of bytes; null on error.
         */
        public final byte[] recv(int flags)
        {
            zmq.Msg msg = base.recv(flags);

            if (msg != null) {
                return msg.data();
            }

            mayRaise();
            return null;
        }

        private void mayRaise()
        {
            int errno = base.errno();
            if (errno != 0 && errno != zmq.ZError.EAGAIN) {
                throw new ZMQException(errno);
            }
        }
```

so you can change recv(int flags) and mayRaise() function